# How to configure video memory for integrated GPU

Tags: memory, gpu, integrated-graphics

I have recently purchased for work a new Dell XPS 13 with 16 GB RAM, which has an integrated Intel GPU.

Reading the properties of the GPU I see this:

```
Available Graphics Memory: 8320 MB
Dedicated Video Memory:     128 MB
System Video Memory:          0 MB
Shared System Memory:      8192 MB
```

It seems to me that the GPU has a very small amout of dedicated video RAM, and can share up to 8 GB of System RAM, taking it from the OS.

Is there a way to **reduce** that maximum shareable RAM value? Or, if not needed/used, does it remain available to the OS for other programs?

Answer (score 3):

Shared memory is just that: *shared*.

It is there ready to be used by either the CPU or GPU, but until it is actually needed it is not allocated to either side. It is ready to be used if needed by the GPU, but until then it is free for the system to use.